# Programming with Java Bytecode

Tags: java

Can Somebody tell me what is the Bytecode Engineering Library (BCEL) and how can i get it?

Comment: You might like to say why you have an interest in ByteCode programming as there is lots of libraries which do many of the useful things you can do.

Comment: If you don't know what it is, then why do you want to get it?

Answer (score 2):

From the [web site](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/):

> The Byte Code Engineering Library is intended to give users a convenient possibility to analyze, create, and manipulate (binary) Java class files (those ending with .class). Classes are represented by objects which contain all the symbolic information of the given class: methods, fields and byte code instructions, in particular.

Get it from the [downloads page](http://jakarta.apache.org/site/downloads/downloads_bcel.cgi).

(And yes, simply typing BCEL into Google would have told you all of this...)

Answer (score 2):

From the Jakarta Project, here is the BCEL definition:

> The Byte Code Engineering Library is intended to give users a convenient possibility to analyze, create, and manipulate (binary) Java class files (those ending with .class). Classes are represented by objects which contain all the symbolic information of the given class: methods, fields and byte code instructions, in particular.
>
> Such objects can be read from an
>   existing file, be transformed by a
>   program (e.g. a class loader at
>   run-time) and dumped to a file again.
>   An even more interesting application
>   is the creation of classes from
>   scratch at run-time. The Byte Code
>   Engineering Library (BCEL) may be also
>   useful if you want to learn about the
>   Java Virtual Machine (JVM) and the
>   format of Java .class files.
>
> BCEL contains a byte code verifier
>   named JustIce, which usually gives you
>   much better information about what's
>   wrong with your code than the standard
>   JVM message.

Here is your resource for BCEL: http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/manual.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a builtin copy, but if you want to download it I would suggest you find it with google.  I prefer ObjectWeb ASM and there is also cglib and javassist.